# Display an yup error when both fields are empty and a toggle is false

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'd like to show an error under the MUI `<Autocomplete />` fields whenever both the `categories` and `products` arrays are empty on submit and `applyToAll` hasn't been selected. Currently I only clear the error when `applyToAll` has been selected. I need the `products` error to disappear, when a category has been added and vice-versa:

```
import { TFunction } from 'i18next';
import * as yup from 'yup';

export const getValidationSchema = (t: TFunction) => yup.object({
    applyToAll: yup
        .boolean(),
categories: yup.array()
    .when('applyToAll', {
        is: false,
        then: yup
            .array()
            .test({
                message: t('promo.categories.required', { ns: 'validations' }),
                test: (categories) => categories?.length > 0 || yup.ref('products') > 0;
            }),
    }),
products: yup.array()
    .when('applyToAll', {
        is: false,
        then: yup
            .array()
            .test({
                message: t('promo.products.required', { ns: 'validations' }),
                test: (products) => products?.length > 0 || yup.ref('categories') > 0;
            }),
    }),
```

I cannot use `.length` on the `ref` object